# Seperate between Admin and client in the same React web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, client, admin

I'm making a web application using MERN Stack, it has an admin dashboard to insert, delete or update the data that the client is going to need in his side of the app, and I just said there's the client side of the app.
What I want to do is to make the browser to seperate between Admin and Client users of the app so that when an Admin opens it, the browser will know that it's an admin and show the Admin Dashboard and when it's a client the browser knows it and shows him the client app.
I don't want a client to find himself in the Admin Dashboard by accident

Comment: You have to implement roles in your system. When a user login in system then check  if user is admin or client the on bases of this check you can change route stack.

Comment: Problem is that the client doesn't have to login, it's a virtual queue management system and doesn't really need authentification on the client side all that he's going to do with it is book a ticket in the queue

Comment: Then make Public routes and Private Routes in React client will access public routes only with doesn't need any auth token and Admin access Private route which is only accessible on auth token